# Relationship Between Integral of CDF and Probability

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ denote the cumulative distribution function and the probability density function of a standard normal variable. Does
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-a) f(x)dx,
$$
where $a$ is a constant, express *some* probability? And if it does, does such a result hold for other distributions?

Thanks a lot, everybody.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I have never seen such an expression in prob. theory.

Comment: For $a=0$ and for any distribution a simple change of variable yields: $$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(x)\,f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1F\,dF=\frac{1}{2}\,.
$$ This is the expected value of a $U(0,1)$ variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $X, Y \text{ i.i.d. } \sim F$ ($F$ can be any general distribution, not necessarily standard normal distribution), this is the probability of $P[X - Y \geq a]$, simply because (check *Probability and Measure*, Theorem 20.3):
\begin{align}
P[X - Y \geq a] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[x - Y \geq a]f(x)dx = 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty P[Y \leq x - a]f(x)dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x - a)f(x)dx.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've just checked _Probability and Measure_, as you suggested, and now I grasp it.